# Assigning a value to a variable in a loop and printing it outside the loop using korn shell

Tags: unix

I am having problem when trying to assign a value to a variable in a loop and trying to print it     outside the loop using korn shell. I want to use that variable in later part of my script. So I am trying to test  by printing the value of the dynamic variable. I just assigned to it from my array.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
clear
BINPATH=/usr/bin
SVR_LIST=servers_list

set -A SERVERS `cat $SVR_LIST`
typeset -i i=0
Sn=${#SERVERS[@]}
#echo "Number of servers in an array are .................." $Sn
while [ $i -lt ${#SERVERS[@]} ] ; do
#print ${SERVERS[$i]}
typeset -l s${i}=${SERVERS[$i]}
#eval echo "Value of Variable is" \${s$i}
#s=\${s$i}
(( i=i+1 ))
done
s=\${s$i}
eval echo "value of s is " $s


s=eval \${s0}
APPSERVER1=$s
echo $APPSERVER1
s=eval \${s1}
APPSERVER2=$s
echo $APPSERVER2

I am getting following error.

value of s is
./variableTest.sh[21]: ${s0}:not found
${s4}
./variableTest.sh[24]: ${s1}:not found
${s4}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is working code…

```
#!/bin/ksh
clear
#BINPATH=/usr/bin
SVR_LIST=test

set -A SERVERS `cat $SVR_LIST`
typeset -i i=0
Sn=${#SERVERS[@]}
#echo "Number of servers in an array are .................." $Sn
while [ $i -lt ${#SERVERS[@]} ] ; do
#print ${SERVERS[$i]}
typeset -l s${i}=${SERVERS[$i]}
eval echo "Value of Variable is" \${s$i}
#s=\${s$i}
(( i=i+1 ))
done

#NOTE THIS LINE i value is i+1 here..
#so if you had last variable as s10=abc you are using s11 outside the loop in follwoing two lines..now its s10
let i=i-1
s=\${s$i}
eval echo "value of s is " $s

#CHANGES HERE
s=$s0
APPSERVER1=$s
echo $APPSERVER1
s=$s1
APPSERVER2=$s
echo $APPSERVER2
```

output...

```
Value of Variable is "credit":
Value of Variable is "wic":
Value of Variable is "wiccash": 
Value of Variable is "sfmnp":
Value of Variable is "snap":
Value of Variable is "baked goods":
Value of Variable is "baked goods":
"credit":
"wic":
```